# Azure Devops pipeline: import variables from template and declare variables in the same variables block

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way that we can mix the variable reuse with template and variable declaration in the same `variables` block ?
Something like this:

```
variables:
  - template: vars.yml  # Template reference
  anotherVar: http://$(oneVarFromVarsYml)/xxx
```

After the test, it doesn't work, I would like to know if you have a workaround.
I know I can define the var `anotherVar`  in the same template `vars.yml`,  but I have the needs to define it directly here not in the template.

The below official Azure Devops docs gives only how to import vars from a template, but it doesn't provide an example for case we have mixed template vars and direct vars:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section of Azure docs mentions it:

If you use both variables and variable groups, use the `name/value` syntax for the individual non-grouped variables:

YAML

```
variables:
- group: my-variable-group
- name: my-bare-variable
  value: 'value of my-bare-variable'
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group

Comment: thx, you're right, in fact, it needs more examples in the templates doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#variable-reuse

Answer (score 12):

Yes, should work. I'm doing something like that as well.

```
variables:
- template: config/configuration.yaml  # contains (amongst others) a var "bar"

- name: 'testVar'
  value: 'foo-$(bar)'
```

Comment: many thx, you're the hero!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved it @XiangZHU

Comment: one more question, we need to reuse a variable template from another repository, so I tried by using resource, but the pipeline says `Unexpected value 'resources'`, do you have any ideas about that ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories

Comment: I found the solution by myself just now